# How to edit data for individual WP Google Maps markers (WP Google Maps)

Tags: javascript, arrays, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So, I have [a website](https://tattooexpert.co.uk) that uses the “WP Google Maps” plugin. It’s a bit customised and pulls all of the data for Tattoo Parlours that are registered in Google Places and displays them as a marker on our site. From here, you can then click “click here for more info” and it shows you the parlours google place reviews. The website isn’t styled yet though so I apologise for how bad it looks.

What I’m trying to do is give each parlour marker a “Send message” feature underneath the “click here for more info” text. Right now it just links to a generic coming soon page and it displays on every marker on the site. I want it so that it links you to their Facebook messenger link (for example: https://messenger.com/t/asos).

I’m trying to figure out the best way to do this - I don’t mind adding marker send message data automatically right now since I just want to get it working first. I’ve done some research but I couldn’t find anything that directly mentions anything like this.

Here’s the current code for the markers:

```
                        //assign an infowindow to the marker so that when its clicked it shows the name of the place
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, x) {
                        return function () {
                            infowindow.setContent("<div class='no-scroll'><strong>" + results[x]['place']['name'] + "</strong><br><br>"
                                + results[x]['place']['address'] + "<br><br>"
                                + "<span style=\"display:table;margin:0 auto; color: #e7711b;\">"
                                + results[x]['place']['rating'] + "&nbsp;" + WPacStars.rating_render(results[x]['place']['rating'], 16, 'e7711b')
                                + "</span>"
                                +"<div id='more_info' align='center' style='margin: 0 auto;'>"
                                + "<a href='" + WPURLS.siteurl + "/reviews?place_id=" + results[x]['place']['id']
                                + "' target='_blank' style='text-align: center; display: block; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px;text-decoration: none; font-size: 16px; color: #6495ed'>click here for more info</a>"
                                + "<a href=‘https://messenger.com/t/asos' style='text-align: center; display: block; text-decoration: none; font-size: 14px; text-decoration: none; color: #6495ed'>Send Message</a>"
                                + "</div></div>");
                            infowindow.open(MYMAP.map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, x));
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
//}}

};
```

Here’s the code what I tried and thought might work. I wasn’t sure if an if statement was the best way to go about it.

```
  //assign an infowindow to the marker so that when its clicked it shows the name of the place
                    if ['place_id' 1] google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, x) {
                        return function () {
                            infowindow.setContent("<div class='no-scroll'><strong>" + results[x]['place']['name'] + "</strong><br><br>"
                                + results[x]['place']['address'] + "<br><br>"
                                + "<span style=\"display:table;margin:0 auto; color: #e7711b;\">"
                                + results[x]['place']['rating'] + "&nbsp;" + WPacStars.rating_render(results[x]['place']['rating'], 16, 'e7711b')
                                + "</span>"
                                +"<div id='more_info' align='center' style='margin: 0 auto;'>"
                                + "<a href='" + WPURLS.siteurl + "/reviews?place_id=1"
                                + "' target='_blank' style='text-align: center; display: block; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px;text-decoration: none; font-size: 16px; color: #6495ed'>click here for more info</a>"
                                + "<a href='https://www.facebook.' style='text-align: center; display: block; text-decoration: none; font-size: 14px; text-decoration: none; color: #6495ed'>Send Message</a>"
                                + "</div></div>");
                            infowindow.open(MYMAP.map, marker);

                        else google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, x) {
                        return function () {
                            infowindow.setContent("<div class='no-scroll'><strong>" + results[x]['place']['name'] + "</strong><br><br>"
                                + results[x]['place']['address'] + "<br><br>"
                                + "<span style=\"display:table;margin:0 auto; color: #e7711b;\">"
                                + results[x]['place']['rating'] + "&nbsp;" + WPacStars.rating_render(results[x]['place']['rating'], 16, 'e7711b')
                                + "</span>"
                                +"<div id='more_info' align='center' style='margin: 0 auto;'>"
                                + "<a href='" + WPURLS.siteurl + "/reviews?place_id=" + results[x]['place']['id']
                                + "' target='_blank' style='text-align: center; display: block; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px;text-decoration: none; font-size: 16px; color: #6495ed'>click here for more info</a>"
                                + "<a href='/coming-soon' style='text-align: center; display: block; text-decoration: none; font-size: 14px; text-decoration: none; color: #6495ed'>Send Message</a>"
                                + "</div></div>");
                            infowindow.open(MYMAP.map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, x));
                }
            }
        }
}
//}}
};
```

Any guidance/help would be great! I’m still learning so feel free to be brutal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put conditional content into your infowindow, don't make an if statement for the listener. Instead, make an if statement inside the listener and place the anchor html in a variable. That way you can control whether or not the the link will show up, and have better code. Example:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, x) {
   return function() {
     var messengerLink;
     if (messengerLinkExists) {
       messengerLink = "<a href=‘https://messenger.com/t/asos' style='text-align: center; display: block; text-decoration: none; font-size: 14px; text-decoration: none; color: #6495ed' target='_blank'>Send Message</a>";
     } else {
       messengerLink = '';
     }
     infowindow.setContent(
     "<div class='no-scroll'><strong>" + results[x]['place']['name'] + "</strong><br><br>" + results[x]['place']['address'] + "<br><br>" + "<span style=\"display:table;margin:0 auto; color: #e7711b;\">" + results[x]['place']['rating'] + "&nbsp;" + WPacStars.rating_render(results[x]['place']['rating'], 16, 'e7711b') + "</span>" + "<div id='more_info' align='center' style='margin: 0 auto;'>" + "<a href='" + WPURLS.siteurl + "/reviews?place_id=" + results[x]['place']['id'] + "' target='_blank' style='text-align: center; display: block; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px;text-decoration: none; font-size: 16px; color: #6495ed'>click here for more info</a>" + messengerLink + "</div></div>");

     infowindow.open(MYMAP.map, marker);
   }
 })(marker, x));
```

Now I'm not sure where you plan to get the messenger link. Your `results.php` does not have that and it's also not included in Places API response. Learn more about what Places API returns [in this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_responses)
If you were hoping the data was part of the Places API response then you might be at a loss there.

Your site is also getting a RetiredVersion warning:

> Google Maps API warning: RetiredVersion https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#retired-version

Since you are using a plugin, it might be wise to update it.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you Henris that really helped a lot! Nice one mate. I was hoping to maybe create a new post type called "Messenger" or something, then maybe input all of the messenger links myself manually - then, I can hopefully link up the markers individually to the correct messenger link. But I'll cross that bridge when I come to it haha!

Comment: Sure! If my answer helped you, you could also accept my answer so that it could help me and others as well :)

Comment: Cheers mate, I did! :) If I wanted to create messenger as a custom post type (so that I can manually add messenger info - could I refer to the custom post type here in the variable setup that you mentioned?

Comment: I don't see why not. When you get there and you encounter difficulties with your infowindow, just post another question and your code in a [minimal, verifiable and complete way](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and there will be a lot who will offer help. :)